# What changes my images location to nas/wp/www/cluster?

Tags: php, wordpress

In trying to debug an issue, there is a Wordpress image slider. It uses ePanel and Chameleon theme. You can set the featured image and the theme will display the featured image in a slider on the home page.

Set up the image for the post as a featured image, save, view the front page it works. Refresh the page 30-seconds later the image is gone. Looking at the page source when the image works it's found at [sitename]/wp-content/uploads/et_temp/Image.png

When the image doesn't work (30 seconds later) it somehow is now looking for the image at [sitename]/nas/wp/www/cluster-####/wp-content/uploads/et_temp/Image.png

Where could the /nas/wp/www/cluster-#### possibly have come from? Confused on where to start looking.

Comment: Sounds like your theme is out of date and is using `upload_path`. Go into your database to the settings table and see if there is a value set for `upload_path`. If there is something there, delete it so it's blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these options to display images on wordpress,

```
src="<?php echo base_url()?>your_theme_dir/image_dir/img.ext"

OR

src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/image_dir/img.ext"
```

Comment: This would work on images he adds inside of posts, but I am not aware of any way to set or modify the `src` attribute on a featured image. It only lets you select the featured image from your uploads.

Comment: try to check any uneven plugin got installed on your wordpress site, and try to uninstall them